# PHP Convert datetime to week

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my table I have a column `date (datetime)`. This is the value: `2020-08-03 16:25:26`

I am trying to convert that into weekday using php. How can I accomplish this?

I tried this: (but it doesn't give me anything)

```
$datee = "2020-08-03 16:25:26";
$datee = strtotime( str_replace("/", "-", $datee));
echo weekOfMonth($datee);
```

And the script:

```
<script>
    function weekOfMonth($date) {
    //Get the first day of the month.
    $firstOfMonth = strtotime(date("Y-m-01", $date));
    //Apply above formula.
    return intval(date("W", $date)) - intval(date("W", $firstOfMonth)) + 1;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You mixed the code from PHP and JS up. javascript hasn't any $ for the name of variables.

Comment: `$` is a valid character in a variable name in javascript (which is why jquery gets away with making it "special" seeming).  It's not a special character, like in PHP, but it's still valid.  I agree that it's unusual - and probably a mistake - to prefix js vars with `$`

Answer (score 0):

Use [strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

```
strftime("%A", strtotime( str_replace("/", "-", $datee)))
```